# DIfferent DB size for same DB hosted on AWS DocumentDB and Atlas Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have DB hosted on Atlas Mongo.
After creating a dump and restoring it on AWS mongo, same DB with same count of documents has x2 bigger `fileSize`

What might be a reason for that?

Comment: I have no idea but I love to investigate things like this. How do you get file size in both cases ?

Comment: @poleszcz with command `db.runCommand( {
   dbStats: 1      
} )`

Comment: what is the mongo storage engine in your db ? WiredTiger ? Is there any encryption done on the source or target db ?

Comment: @poleszcz I can't check it. Command `db.serverStatus()` returns error Not Authorized. Moreover, there was a mistake in my question.  I migrated data from Atlas to AWS DocumentDB. I wanted to check `dataSize` ( not `fileSize` or `storageSize`) but command to get db stats does not return field `dataSize` on AWS DocumentDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's WiredTiger storage engine supports [compression for all collections and indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression). Documents are compressed using block-level compression (`snappy` by default, with `zlib` and `zstd` options) and indexes use prefix compression.

AWS DocumentDB is an emulation of a subset of MongoDB server features, and currently does not have support for storage compression. Per [Functional Differences: Amazon DocumentDB and MongoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.functional-benefits):

> Amazon DocumentDB doesn't currently support compression for stored data or indexes. Data sizes for stored data and indexes might be larger than when you use other options.